# c++ vector pointer

Tags: c++

How do i make vector which will have pointers in it?
Tried this but failed.

```
vector<*struct_gene> vector_child_genes;
```

full code if some one is interested http://codepad.org/50qrNZvd

Comment: What else have you tried? There are not that many combinations :)

Comment: Do you usually declare pointers with the * before the type?

Comment: Taking a glimpse at the source code, are you sure you need pointers at all?  Not just a vector of `struct_genes`?

Comment: @Greg: Elements in vectors *are* on the heap.

Comment: Brian R. Bondy : yes i usually declare pointers type *pointer_name.
Justin Ardini : i think i need. i have vector with all posible genes. Then i am making usnit and taking for each unit 12 posible genes. And lastly to breed a child i am planing to make vector with pointers what points to  all posiblle parent genes and then randomly picking 12 genes for the child.

Comment: @kurrata:  "I usually declare pointers `type *pointer_name`:"  Exactly; the asterisk in the pointer declaration goes _after_ the type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
vector<struct_gene *> vector_child_genes;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
vector<struct_gene*> vector_child_genes;
```

You specify a type in the angle brackets of the vector, and pointer types are specified with a postfix asterisk, not a prefix asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

You put the type inside the brackets.  There is no special syntax otherwise.  If you normally declare a pointer with a * after the type (I hope so) then you still do that same thing.